# MATLAB solve ODE on invariant manifold

Tags: matlab, ode

I have a system that looks like

```
dn/dt=f(n,v)
dh/dt=g(h,v)
```

I want to solve this equation on the manifold `F(v,n,h)=0`, a nonlinear function in `v`. I tried to use something like `v=fzero(@(x) F(x,n,h),0)` to solve for the value of v on the manifold at each time step. But this is incredibly slow and ode15s (my system is a relaxation oscillator) fails to meet integration tolerance. How do I find solution to the ODE on the manifold defined by `F(v,n,h)=0`?

Comment: You should employ a DAE solver, as your system is differential-algebraic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find @LutzL's comment very helpful. It is possible to set up a DAE solver using `ode15s`.
Example: The "Solve Robertson Problem as Semi-Explicit Differential Algebraic Equations (DAEs)" section in https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode15s.html

In my case, I would setup a matrix:

```
M=[zeros(1,3);0,1,0;0,0,1];
options = odeset('Mass',M,'RelTol',1e-5,'AbsTol',1e-6,'MaxStep',0.01);
y0=[v0,n0,h0];
[T,Y]=ode15s(@slow,[0 50],y0,options);
```

And `slow` is a function defined as:

```
function dy = slow(t,y)
    v=y(1); n=y(2); h=y(3);
    dy=zeros(3,1);
    dy(1)=F(v,n,h);
    dy(2)=f(n,v);
    dy(3)=g(h,v);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways to solve this problem is to differentiate
the `F(v,n,h)=0` equation:

[image]

Now we can obtain the ODE system

[image]

or

[image]

which can be solved in the usual way.

Comment: I have tried this way. However, the dF/dv term becomes very close to 0 near a fold structure in the system. Hence the solution precision is not very good.